# make + bash: setting environment variables on command line doesn't work

Tags: linux-kernel, make

I am trying to build the kernel for `Raspberry-pi` on my `Debian-8` host machine. I passed the following commands to build the kernel

```
make ARCH=arm KERNEL=kernel CROSS_COMPILE=arm-liux-gnueabihf- bcmrpi_defconfig
```

The error I get is:

```
make: gcc: Command not found
```

I have intentionally not installed `'gcc'`  on my machine, since the cross-tool-chain should be enough. It appears to me that the variable value set for `CROSS_COMPILE` is not getting set for the `make` program. What could be the reason?

PS: my `bash` version is

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: try it this way: `ARCH=arm KERNEL=kernel CROSS_COMPILE=arm-liux-gnueabihf- make bcmrpi_defconfig`

Answer (score 1):

I was invoking this `make` command from another `makefile`, which means I should export the variables in such case.

The following post explains this topic in detail 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make